# Parse Link/Unlink user completion blocks never called (Twitter/Facebook)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to add link/unlink functionality for both Twitter and Facebook via the Parse iOS SDK but I am having an issue I've never encountered before - the completion blocks for link and unlink user are never being called. The following is the code I am using for link / unlink functionality and I was wondering if anyone has encountered something similar before and might have any ideas as to what the problem is. Thanks

```
@IBAction func atnFacebookConnect(sender: AnyObject) {
    disableUserInteraction()
    self.actFacebookConnect.startAnimating()
    let permissions = ["email","public_profile","user_about_me"]
    if btnFacebookConnect.titleLabel?.text == "Disconnect" {
        if let user = User.currentUser() {
            PFFacebookUtils.unlinkUserInBackground(user, block: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil && success == true {
                    self.checkIfUserIsLinkedToSocialMedia()
                }
                else {
                    iLikeyAlert(self, "", "Something went wrong", nil)
                }
                self.actFacebookConnect.stopAnimating()
                self.enableUserInteraction()
            })
        }
    }
    else if btnFacebookConnect.titleLabel?.text == "Connect" {
        if let user = User.currentUser() {
            PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user, withReadPermissions:permissions, block: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil && success == true {
                    self.checkIfUserIsLinkedToSocialMedia()
                }
                else {
                    iLikeyAlert(self, "", "Something went wrong", nil)
                }
                self.actFacebookConnect.stopAnimating()
                self.enableUserInteraction()
            })
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func atnTwitterConnect(sender: AnyObject) {
    disableUserInteraction()
    self.actTwitterConnect.startAnimating()
    if btnTwitterConnect.titleLabel?.text == "Disconnect" {
        if let user = User.currentUser() {
            PFTwitterUtils.unlinkUserInBackground(user, block: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil && success == true {
                    self.checkIfUserIsLinkedToSocialMedia()
                }
                else {
                    iLikeyAlert(self, "", "Something went wrong", nil)
                }
                self.actTwitterConnect.stopAnimating()
                self.enableUserInteraction()
            })
        }
    }
    else if btnTwitterConnect.titleLabel?.text == "Connect" {
        if let user = User.currentUser() {
            PFTwitterUtils.linkUser(user, block: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil && success == true {
                    self.checkIfUserIsLinkedToSocialMedia()
                }
                else {
                    iLikeyAlert(self, "", "Something went wrong", nil)
                }
                self.actTwitterConnect.stopAnimating()
                self.enableUserInteraction()
            })
        }
    }
}
```